# No output in Slurm.out

Tags: slurm, osc

I have submitted a Slurm job to a server, and while I can view the outputs on the terminal, there is no output being generated in the `slurm.out` file. Surprisingly, there are no errors reported, and the job appears to be running smoothly. However, my objective is to be able to monitor the job's output in the `slurm.out` file.

Is there a recommended approach or solution to ensure that the output is properly captured and recorded in the `slurm.out` file for monitoring purposes?

Tested with a hello world

Comment: If you can view the output on the terminal, it probably was not correctly submitted but rather simply executed. What command did you run to submit it?

Comment: To clarify, when I test the code on my local machine, I can successfully run it without encountering any errors, and the output is displayed on the terminal. However, when I train the model on a supercomputer by submitting a Slurm job using the command 'sbatch run.sh', I am unable to see the output as I did before on the terminal. It is important for me to visually observe the progress of the model and ensure that it is running smoothly. I could do this with other model, but not on this model that is based on TF1 (which is quite old).

Comment: There are multiple buffers involved between the job output and the visualisation of the file from the login node. The information is not necessarily instantly propagated. You can try using the [sattach](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sattach.html) command.

Comment: can you share the job script? We can't help you without the job script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with python scripts.

Some tips

1. In sbatch file

```
#!/bin/bash

    #SBATCH --output=python.%j.out
    #SBATCH --error=python.%j.err
    #SBATCH -N 1
    #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1 

    export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE

    srun python yourscript.py
```

2. Print in python

   `print ("Hello World ", flush=True`
   or
   `print ("Hello World ",file=sys.stdout)`
3. Do not forget in python script import sys